# How to restrict power output to a USB client?

Tags: usb, current-limiting

...or, how not to charge my phone when I'm using it as a GSM modem in USB tether mode?

I've asked this on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182171/how-to-restrict-cut-power-output-to-a-usb-client) but it seems there's no simple way to do it in software.

The problem:

In USB tether mode, the phone wrecks the netbook battery by charging from it. I'd like to be able to maintain the data connection while restricting the current fed over the power lines; let the phone and the netbook use their own batteries without draining each other.

It seems I can't cut VBUS entirely, as [device detection won't work](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.usb.general/61206). But I ponder the case where I allow the OS and the device to negotiate the power as they desire, then simply fail to deliver - some kind of current-limiting circuitry in the USB cable, so that the phone draws some 100mA or even less no matter how much the host allows to source. If that worked, detection should still work, data lines are unaffected, and the trickle doesn't put much strain on the netbook batteries.

- Would that work?
- If it would, what would be the best way to restrict the current - simple, robust and preferably not wasting the excess...

Comment: There's no way to really know what will happen to the phone when you restrict current to it. Most likely, the voltage will drop (because the phone tries to pull full current) and then the phone will think the computer has disconnected.

Comment: Why not try the opposite - negotiate only 100 mA. The phone should then refrain from charging. If you can't modify the USB drivers, perhaps as an experiment you could plug in a few devices (and a hub?) that negotiate away most of the power, so the netbook has none left to give the phone.

Comment: @tomnexus: the linked discussion states that while the device can present several power profiles and the host can pick one, almost all devices present just one profile, and if the host declines it, the device will just disconnect.

Comment: @SF hmmm yes I see. Well it is probably worth a try adding a resistor to the +5V line. Try a few values around 5-10 Ohm. Perhaps it does work and your phone just charges very slowly.